# NestedScrollView inside a ReyciclerView not scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-scrollview, android-nestedscrollview

I have a `ViewPager`, that contains a `RecyclerView` which scrolls vertically and displays items with an adapter. Each item haves a `NestedScrollView`, which also should scroll vertically. The problem is that when I try to scroll that `NestedScrollView`, it scrolls the parent `ViewPager`.

How can i solve this problem?

This is the RecyclerView:

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/offersRecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/table_cell_background"
    android:fadeScrollbars="false"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

This is the layout of the items, which contains the NestedScrollView:

```
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/statusConstraintLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/table_background"
        android:padding="@dimen/spacing_small"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/salaryConstraintLayout"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.55">

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/statusValue"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/offer_sent_with_three_dots"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/mini_text"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Is the ViewPager vertical or horizontal?

Comment: Also, I haven't tested this so it may or may not work, but give ViewPager2 a try: it's based on RecyclerView and thus should handle nested scrolling a bit better.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can try this in the RecyclerView

```
android:nestedScrollingEnabled="true"
```

Comment: Can the items layout of ConstraintLayout be restricted on layout_height. Here match parent is used. Can you change to wrap_content instead and check?

Answer (score 0):

try with by add this attribute `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` to nestedScrollView